# Expressive text to speech techniques in C#

Tags: c#, text-to-speech

I was wondering if there is a voice class in C# that I can use to change the tone of the voice? Such as the pitch, F0 mean and so on.

If there isn't such a voice library in C#, what library should I import that is multilingual and that doesn't require an online connection?

I want to make use of the class to add emotions to the speech when making use of text-to-speech.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the assembly [`System.Speech`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145021(v=vs.110).aspx) to your project. There you have the namespace `System.Speech.Synthesis`. Then you find the class [`SpeechSynthesizer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.synthesis.speechsynthesizer(v=vs.110).aspx). Try to use this for using text-to-speech.